# Python package installation from tarball results in 0.0.0 version

Tags: python, installation, pip, package

I'm installing Python packages from the tar.gz source distributions from PyPi but sometimes those packages get installed with a version of "0.0.0".

Can anyone help me understand why that is the case and how to resolve this?

As a recent example I took datacube from https://pypi.org/project/datacube/#files (yes I could use the whl file here, but generically I'd prefer the tar.gz)

- Download datacube-1.8.3.tar.gz
- Extract and cd to datacube folder
- `pip install -v .`

When using a Python 3.8.6 it seemingly installs fine and the version is 1.8.3 as expected ("Successfully installed datacube-1.8.3")

When using Python 3.8.2 with a slightly different set of installed modules the resulting version is instead 0.0.0 ("Successfully installed datacube-0.0.0")

In both cases I'm using a virtualenv (20.0.34 / 20.0.18)

So where does the version exactly come from, how can I check and resolve that?

I already tried `pip install --upgrade setuptools setuptools-scm toml poetry` which were IMO the packages responsible for installing packages, but to no avail.

After an "accident" when experimenting I've also noticed, that the problem seemingly vanishes once I run the pip install command outside of the virtualenv which is even more mysterious as I created it with `virtualenv --system-site-packages` and `pip freeze` shows no difference

Comment: Downloading the tarball and manually installing it seems like a weird thing to prefer. Why do you not simply `pip install datacube`?

Comment: This is part of something larger. In this case EasyBuild which installs software and dependencies semi-automatically. It allows pre-downloading and checksumming sources for reproducibility and for clusters without internet connection. So installing directly from PyPi is not an option here

Comment: Even then you can install the tarball with `pip` from a local repo. I can see no benefit from manually untarring it, and assume it's not something the maintainer expected to need to support.

Comment: Isn't that what pip does under the hood anyway when no matching whl was found? I mean using the tar.gz, unzipping it and installing from (that) source?
Also it does work for pretty much everything and I'm seemingly "only" running into a Python issue which I don't know how to debug further